How to render chartjs with last 24 hours on X axis with php and mysql?
I want to generate a chart from mysql results with this table :

I need to have last 24 hours on X axis, Y axis got the number of reports per hours (Its ok)
Here is the code and actual render :
https://jsfiddle.net/g3L8f4hm/
The php code :
<?php

$dataPoints = array();

//____________________________MySQLI Prepared Statements__________________________________

$query_s1 = mysqli_query($bdd, 'select date_format(`signalements`.`date_submit`,"%H:%m") as `date_submit`,count(`signalements`.`id`) as `id` from `signalements` group by year(`signalements`.`date_submit`),month(`signalements`.`date_submit`),day(`signalements`.`date_submit`), hour(`signalements`.`date_submit`),date_format(`signalements`.`date_submit`,"%H:%m") order by year(`signalements`.`date_submit`),month(`signalements`.`date_submit`),day(`signalements`.`date_submit`), hour(`signalements`.`date_submit`)');

/*
if($stmt = $bdd->prepare($query_s1)){


   $stmt->execute() or trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);


   $result = $stmt->get_result();
   
   $row_signalements = $result->fetch_assoc();


   $nb_signalements = $result->num_rows;
}
*/

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_s1)) {

$nb = $row['id'];

echo ''.$row['date_submit'].'<br>';

//$dataPoints[] = array("y" => $row['total_membre_mois'], "label" => $row['join_date']);

$dataPoints[] = array("y" => $row['id'], "z" => $row['id'], "label" => $row['date_submit']);


}
?>



 <script>
    window.onload = function () {
     
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        animationEnabled: true,
        animationDuration: 2000,   //change to 1000, 500 etc
        //backgroundColor: "#F5DEB3",
        //width: 320, 
        theme: "light1", // Default: “light1” Options: “light1″,”light2”, “dark1”, “dark2” 
        title:{
        text: "Nombre de signalements", 
        fontWeight: "bolder",
        fontColor: "#008B8B",
        fontFamily: "tahoma",        
        
        fontSize: 25,
        padding: 10        
      },
     axisX:{
      //valueFormatString: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
      valueFormatString: "HH:mm",
      interval: 1,
      intervalType: "hour",
      labelFontSize: 9,
      labelFormatter: function(e){
      return CanvasJS.formatDate(e.value, "HH:mm");
    }
    },
        axisY: {
            title: "Nombre de signalements"
        },
        data: [{
            type: "splineArea",
        color: "#FF0000",
        markerSize: 5,
            indexLabelPlacement: 'outside',
            indexLabelOrientation: 'horizontal',
            dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
        }]
    });
    chart.render();
     
    }
    </script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>  



Actually my X axis looks like 01:00 01:00  01:00  01:00  01:00 , i want to render the last 24 hours on X axis with chartsjs library.
Thank you a lot for your help, it will be very appreciated.

As far as I can see you ought to remove the labelFormatter - the incoming data is already in HH:mm format - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/shzd5Lyp/. But also, without the dates, the data looks a little odd - you're only showing times, and the times aren't in a sensible order. Ordering your SQL query by year/month/day doesn't seem to make a lot of sense when you're grouping the date from many different dates into one time point. Althogh, if you only want the last 24 hours that would matter less - but you need to add a WHERE clause in your query to make that happen. Have you tried anything?

Thank you a lot for your help @ADyson, i removed the labelFormatter, and i have just added "WHERE date_submit > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)" before group by. Here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/c0swpy29/ . But it doesnt show 24 hours on X axes with number of reports per hours i'm blocked on this.

It shows the number of reports at the time intervals recorded in the database. That's the data you gave it. If you want it hourly I think you'd have to group the query by hour, not by hour and minute.

I tried but no success :-( I need to have this result : https://i.imgur.com/l6aqsId.png

UPDATE : new sql : $query_s1 = mysqli_query($bdd, 'select date_format(signalements.date_submit,"%Y-%M-%D %H:00") as date_submit,count(signalements.id) as idfromsignalements WHERE date_submit > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) GROUP BY hour(signalements.date_submit),date_format(signalements.date_submit,"%Y-%M-%D %H:00") ORDER BY year(signalements.date_submit),month(signalements.date_submit),day(signalements.date_submit), hour(signalements.date_submit)'); Render is a bit better : https://i.imgur.com/Bb0zAiV.png

ok good. What do you think is missing now?

I need to create rows for empty dates reports as well, (count = 0), for this final result : i.imgur.com/l6aqsId.png

Ok. So really then this is now a SQL question about how to generate rows even where the count = 0, when using a select statement with grouping. Have you done any research on that specifically? I suspect you won't be the first person to have that general problem

Yes i made lot of research, solution could be to create a table with 24 rows, one for each for a hour, then make a left outter join with the first table.

Yep that's a common way to do it

Ok its look like that now : https://i.imgur.com/GF06QXq.png . How can i set the actual hour as max hour on the right of the chart, then remove 24 hours from this value to set the minimum chart ? Here is my actual SQL request : https://paste.gd/Qwv7rCTb

I don't know what you mean by "actual hour as max hour". Do you mean the current hour of the day, at the moment when you ran the query?

Like that : https://i.imgur.com/2O1RwuC.png . its 9AM right now, so i want this value at right of the chart, then remove 24 hours from the actual time to set it to the left.

Hm, I don't think you can do it with your current query because you've hard-coded the hours and their order into the UNION statements. I'm not sure how to do it personally, but I bet the internet will know. I will have a think if I have time

Np thank you a lot for your precious time :-)
